# Best way to handle parquet dataset schemas?

Tags: pyarrow

I generally have wanted to dictate that certain values are a certain type, such as ID columns being a string instead of an integer, and some columns being a dictionary instead of a string, some timestamps having a time zone and others without, etc.

This means that I have normally created an explicit schema in advance, and then I use the schema when I transform the data with pandas, and I use the schema when I save the dataset. So every source of data has a schema defined like this:

```
pyarrow_schema = pa.schema(
    [
        ("date", pa.date32()),
        ("date_id", pa.int32()),
        ("r_id", pa.string()),
        ("business", pa.dictionary(index_type=pa.int32(), value_type=pa.string())),
        ("in_utc", pa.timestamp(unit="ns", tz="UTC")),
        ("out_utc", pa.timestamp(unit="ns", tz="UTC")),
        ("seconds", pa.int32())
    ]
)
```

If new columns are added or changed, I need to update my explicit schema. By default, I add missing columns and I email an alert if a new column not in the schema is detected.

It is not terrible because at least there is a clear history of changes in VCS, but I wonder if there is a better way. I think when I set this up it was pyarrow version 0.17, so perhaps some of the issues I faced with schemas have been resolved.

Any suggestions or best practices?

Comment: If you want to have specific control over which types are used for which column (and not rely on the default inferred types), then you need to define such a schema as you show above. But I don't know what "issues I faced with schemas" you had before. You will have to make your question more specific if you want better answers, I think

Comment: Thanks - I would need to check and test again. Some fragments had null values which caused issues but I was also using Dask which might have influenced results. I'll do some testing